# creating a discord bot using reader writer, need help [java.io.FileReader and java.io.Filewriter]

Tags: java, filereader, filewriter

so my main problem is the fact that the reader and writer is not working the way I want it to, no errors other than output errors

do note that everything worked ok before I added the reader and witer. 
also i am newer to coding so if you have any suggestions to make this a little more neet i am also open for suggestions

```
public static void Reader(){

        try {
            FileReader Reader1 = new FileReader(MoonlitShadow.Name);
            FileReader Reader2 = new FileReader(CerberusPack.Name);
            FileReader Reader3 = new FileReader(PhantomThieves.Name);
           if (Reader1.read() != MoonlitShadow.Points || Reader2.read() != CerberusPack.Points || (Reader3.read() != PhantomThieves.Points)) {
               MoonlitShadow.Points = Reader1.read();
               CerberusPack.Points = Reader2.read();
               PhantomThieves.Points = Reader3.read();
           }

           Reader1.close();
           Reader2.close();
           Reader3.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

```
public static void Writer(int POINTS, String NAME) {
        try {

            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(NAME);
            writer.write(POINTS);
            writer.close();
            System.out.print("this has worked");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

```
if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase(Main.prefix + "AddPoints")) {
            if (MoonlitShadow.Points == 0 && PhantomThieves.Points == 0 && CerberusPack.Points == 0) {
                ReaderAndWriter.Reader();
                }
            else if (args[1].equalsIgnoreCase(MoonlitShadow.PackName) || args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("MS")) {
                MoonlitShadow.Points = MoonlitShadow.Points + Integer.parseInt(args[2]);

                EmbedBuilder PackPoints = new EmbedBuilder();
                PackPoints.setColor(MoonlitShadow.Color);
                PackPoints.setTitle("You now have a total of " + MoonlitShadow.Points + " points");
                event.getGuild().getTextChannelById("673551744512425984").getMessageById("674072960516096013").complete().editMessage(PackPoints.build()).queue();
                ReaderAndWriter.Writer(MoonlitShadow.Points, MoonlitShadow.Name);

            }
```

my main problem is that every time I try to get the reader to take the numbers in the file and add them to the variable but it fails at its job and resets with the variable... I am assuming I overlooked something, but also it gives the int a -1, I would like to understand the reasoning behind that and fix it

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: there is no real error in the logs,  its just the bot wont read what is in the text and  ```MoonlitShadow.Points = Reader1.read();``` does not work